# Logging child process used which doesn't log correctly in C

Tags: c, logging, child-process

**Edit**: I have created the child process inside of the main itself. Now I am indeed getting the correct the answer. (I have removed all the other child processes created)
**HOWEVER I HAVE ONE QUESTION:** Why doesn't it work by creating the processes as I've down in the code below?

How I think about it is that the processes will be ended every single time and then a new process will be created.
I reasoned this way mainly because as this is an assignment I wasn't really sure whether I was able to modify the main file itself. Thanks in advance!

I was hoping to get some help with the issue described in the title. I have a child process which will log messages onto a log-file where the messages are being logged but multiple times for some reason.
I have tried to understand the issue here but I can't really figure out where the problem is.

I provide 3 source files here.

1. source_db.

```
FILE* open_db(char *filename, bool append) {
    FILE *fp;
    if (append == true) {
        fp = fopen(filename, "a");
    } else {
        fp = fopen(filename, "w");
    }

    // Error handling for file opening
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("The following error has occurred:");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Communicate with the log process
    create_log_process(); // Create the log process once before opening the data file
    write_to_log_process("Data file opened.");
    end_log_process();
    return fp;
}


int insert_sensor(FILE * f, sensor_id_t id, sensor_value_t value, sensor_ts_t ts) {
    fprintf(f, "%d, %lf, %ld \n", id, value, ts);
    // Communicate with the log process
    create_log_process();
    write_to_log_process("Data inserted.");
    end_log_process();
    return 0;
}

int close_db(FILE * f) {
    fclose(f);
    // Communicate with the log process
    create_log_process();
    write_to_log_process("Data file closed.");
    end_log_process();
    return 0;
}
```

2. logger.c

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 100

FILE *fp;
int fd[2], pid, i;
char received_message[BUFFER_SIZE];

int create_log_process() {
    // log file opening
    fp = fopen("gateway.log", "a");

    // creation of communication and child process
    pipe(fd);
    pid = fork();
    // error handle
    if (pid == -1) {
        perror("fork failed");
        exit(2);
    }
    return 0;
}

int end_log_process() {
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}


int write_to_log_process(char *msg) {
    if (pid == 0) { // child process
        // reading from pipe
        close(fd[1]);
        read(fd[0], received_message, sizeof(received_message));
        close(fd[0]);

        // timestamp creation
        time_t timer;
        time(&timer);
        struct tm *timestamp_info;
        timestamp_info = localtime(&timer);
        char timestamp[20];
        strftime(timestamp, sizeof(timestamp), "%a %b %d %x %Y", timestamp_info);

        // writing message to log file.
        fprintf(fp, "%d - %s - %s\n", i, timestamp, msg);
    } else { // parent process
        // Increment the sequence number only for actual log entries
        i++;

        // Write the message to the pipe in the parent process
        close(fd[0]);
        write(fd[1], msg, sizeof(msg));  // +1 to include the null terminator
        close(fd[1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

3. main.c where an opening, insertion and closing is tested.

```
#include "sensor_db.h"
#include "logger.h"
#include "config.h"

int main()
{
    FILE *f = open_db("sensor_db.csv", true);

    sleep(1);
    sensor_id_t id = 1;
    sensor_value_t v = 0.001;
    sensor_ts_t ts = time(NULL);
    insert_sensor(f, id, v, ts);
    close_db(f);
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried debugging with gbd but couldn't get into the child process after the set follow-fork-mode child for some reason.
**at last the expected output vs the actual output:**

```
0 - Sat Nov 18 11/18/23 - Data file opened.
0 - Sat Nov 18 11/18/23 - Data inserted.
1 - Sat Nov 18 11/18/23 - Data inserted.
1 - Sat Nov 18 11/18/23 - Data file closed.
2 - Sat Nov 18 11/18/23 - Data file closed.
1 - Sat Nov 18 11/18/23 - Data file closed.
0 - Sat Nov 18 11/18/23 - Data file closed.
```

**expected:**

```
0 - Sat Nov 18 11/18/23 - Data file opened.
1 - Sat Nov 18 11/18/23 - Data inserted.
2 - Sat Nov 18 11/18/23 - Data file closed
```

Comment: First, you're forking every time you write to a log, but I never see the process end. Each fork also overwrites the existing values in the global variables, so you lose references to the pid and pipe. Also, both child and parent continue executing the main code. Basically, I think you have to rethink / learn more about managing processes. Looks like what you really want is to fork one process for logging in main which starts a read loop on the pipe, then stop it before exiting.

Comment: Hey! Thank you for the info! It is for an assignment and I thought I wasn't able to put anything into the main file that is why I tried doing it this way as I was a bit lost.

Comment: @JohnBayko Do you suggest me to just fork a process inside of the main file (with creating a pipe) and then using this pipe to communicate every time?
I just thought that I was able to create a process every time and then close it creating a new one.

I have one more question:
What did you mean with there is no end to the process?

Comment: You could create a new process each time, then stop it, but that's not what you're doing. I don't have the time to write a full answer, sorry, but a forked process continues to run until it calls `exit()` or returns from `main()`. I think you expect it stops when you return from the function that created it, but no, it continues exactly like the parent process would. Sorry I can't explain more right now.

Comment: @JohnBayko Exactly!! Thanks a lot for the help... 
indeed, the child processes themselves need to be ended manually which is kind of logical. If f.e. parent process is waiting via wait(NULL) it would only be able to continue if the child process were to return/exit via an exit(). In this context however, I didn't think about that. 
whenever you see this: as a last question, what would normally be more efficient to do, creating child processes every single time or creating one child process in the main with one pipe to read and write every time. I would lean towards the second option I guess?

Comment: There's always some overhead to creating a process. It's not much, but it's there. Threads have less overhead, but they share memory so are easier to mess up. There are cases where you might want to create a new process each time, such as to manage resources or reduce latency, but it depends on the overall structure of your program, and I think mostly I would aim for a single process for something I made.